# Significant Location change battery drain Issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Does anyone know if the significant location change service drains battery or not? I can see a significant drain overnight, approximately 15-20% drain with this service enabled else 5-10% drain.

Answer (score 0):

No, significant location change does not draw much battery at all, at least that’s my experience based on previous testing, albeit a few years ago but also based on how it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.  Is there anyway to check background location tracking when app is terminated? I mean do we have to travel in real time or is there anyway to simulate it ?

Comment: You might be able to simulate on the simulator but on a real phone you’d have to travel (or you a gps simulator device)

Comment: In simulator, we can use the simulation option that's fine. But how to test location updates when app in not running?